# No consigo modificar el ancho de un div con JS

Tags: javascript

Buenas,

Estoy usando un pequeño script para modificar el ancho de un div, que se repite varias veces.

```
<script>
$(function() {
   var ancho_div = document.getElementsByClassName("seccion_logro")[0].offsetWidth;
   var ancho_imagen = document.getElementsByClassName("imagen_logro")[0].offsetWidth;
   var ancho_info_logro = ancho_div - ancho_imagen-1; //el -1 es porque sino se pasa a la otra línea
   var d = document.getElementsByClassName('info_logro')
   console.log(ancho_info_logro) //valor del ancho calculado 344px

   document.getElementsByClassName('info_logro')[0].offsetWidth = ancho_info_logro+"px";
   console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('info_logro')[0].offsetWidth); //Valor de 336px cuando debería ser 344px

   for (var i=0; i<d.length; i=i+1) {
      d[i].offsetWidth = ancho_info_logro + "px";
   }

});
</script>
```

En CSS le he asignado a la clase `info_logro`:

```
.info_logro {
   width: 80%;
}
```

No veo dónde está el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debes modificar `offsetWidth`. Debes modificar `style.width`.

En vez de

```
d[i].offsetWidth = ancho_info_logro + "px";
```

prueba con

```
d[i].style.width = ancho_info_logro + "px";
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Acepto en 5 minutos la respuesta.